# How do I create an automatic 2 week total in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtotal

How do I total a column within a 14 day date period?  I have my data on one page, and would like an automatic 2 week total as I add data on a separate page.

I have tried `SUMIFS` syntax:

```
=SUMIFS(data!N:N,data!A:A,">="&A2,data!A:A,"=<"&B2)
```

- `data!A:A` is dates from data.
- `data!N:N` is a sum of data.
- `A2` is page 2 and is the start date.
- `B2` is page 2 and is the end date.

I get a total of `0`.

See link: **[My workbook on OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmJR-28x1NyeqAeGhU-mSOVEq-YT)**

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works fine. It's just that the dates in the sum sheet are from 2018, but all the dates in the data sheet are from 2017. Hence you get a 0 as the formula result.

Comment: If that solved your issue, please mark it as the answer, as explained in the [tour]